# Typescript This expression is not constructable. error on inherited class structure

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop

I'm new to Typescript and I'm trying to personalize my error classes inside the application.

I have totally four classes; **Exception**, **GenericError**, **BaseService**, **CarService** two main and two inherited. **GenericError** extends **ExceptionClass** and **CarService** extends **BaseService**. I'm not be able to change constructor property of GenericError class. I'm getting this error;

> This expression is not constructable.

[TS Snippet](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFEA8GMFMAcAuBLA9gOwHSIM4ChoAbAQxxwhgRQwGESzRZJFZ0ATc8AJy9S9ADeeUKByJiiAK44AXKHSSAtgCNYXANzDQi2GWIBzWHLFdk6fZpFreXHAH45qZQCtY0RJdDQMJye74AFGIS0nIKKmoANNq6OAZGooim5tHWfPaOLm6IAJSCWiI4kvBqATp6hjmeIogAFsg4mMFS5AC8iSE41aB1DZjlcYag7QPx3b2NabbDjDzpngC%20eEt4IKAA4qxqyNDcNtj4RKTkm%20jbu5RIaOiMzKwcFHBXtPTkQiLe6L7%20XGWx8Q5Esl9Hl3iJRMVSgAWAAMMOioyGAB8kaAAOQASXQLC46GIhAgcy4aKqWiWKzWACFSLAAMpqABuO1gBwIr1A1JwdMZzPyIkMZ1MuyJclO5ygT2o6E0Wk%2030QgURCRMZhBfPBE0wAvFRJmZwA7hstkKJVRrgFSSJyXhVmAaMQuPSuEy4KymPA%20IhQGxYAAzYiSQheo4Me2OnlwW4sdjkTnc528sFypJ%20BW-UEFcGFSG-NEkzNZuWoQgswiofQBABEYadLtgHS4LDYAEJK5bwUsRKQAJ7oaBeWpuADWYYt6pEXFgUlx8lghoACrxFA1YAEe33QAFJzhiwyEsR0N3opPXO45Afu3lWgA%20cfgkAAKgfoAxigMZnrO50oGU0g-DDLfQdh6WoJFAf1kEIcgH2AAsvB8L14GOfU%20A4AA5VBEAAWQkaBaj2PU5xAvptRNIkAjRAAxYhINAAAlWBSAwH8SBY4gSW6Ccp0kGcT2yAIkLIFCuHQzCcMQPC9nbK0cjJZY8CAA)

What is wrong with my class inheritence logic?

```
// Exception.ts
class ExceptionClass extends Error {
  status: number;
  message: string;
  errors?: object;
  constructor(status: number, message: string, errors?: object) {
    super(message);
    this.status = status;
    this.message = message;
    this.errors = errors;
  }
}
```

- 

```
// GenericError.ts
class GenericException extends ExceptionClass {
  constructor(message?: string) {
    super(400, message || 'Internal Error');
  }
}
```

- 

```
// BaseService.ts
class BaseService {
  genericError: GenericException;

  constructor(message: string) {
    this.genericError = new GenericException();
  }
}
```

- 

```
// CarService.ts
export default class CarService extends BaseService {
  constructor() {
        super('')
        console.log("CarService started!");
    }
  async checkCar() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve: any, reject: any) => {
      //** Imagine some business logic that fails */
      const passwordsNotMatchErr = new this.genericError('Fail Reason bla bla');
      return reject(passwordsNotMatchErr);
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up, marking a function async and then returning a promise is pointless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in the following line:

```
const passwordsNotMatchErr = new this.genericError('Fail Reason bla bla');
```

You are trying to create an instance of a variable that has been instantiated in the constructor of your class. You are trying to do something like `const myString = new "I am a string and I can not be instantiated"`

When you do:

```
genericError: GenericException;
```

What you are doing is defining a class variable which is of `GenericExpection` type (Remember that only classes can be instantiated, not variables). If you'd like to follow your architecture you can do something like:

```
  async checkCar() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve: any, reject: any) => {
      //** Imagine some business logic that fails */
      this.genericError = new GenericException('Fail Reason bla bla');
      return reject(this.genericError);
    })
  }
```

or

```
  async checkCar() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve: any, reject: any) => {
      //** Imagine some business logic that fails */
      const passwordsNotMatchErr = new GenericException('Fail Reason bla bla');
      return reject(passwordsNotMatchErr);
    })
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know I can import GenericException class on the top of the service file and use it as you suggested. But I think you are missing my point. I'm trying to gather all exceptions in class and I want to use them in extended classes with **this.**. If I do as you suggested I have to import genericException class in every file, haven't I?

Comment: I see what you want to do... What about creating a helper method in `BaseService` class that returns a new instantiate of `GenericException`? This you will only need to import `GenericException` on the `BaseService` class and just interact with the helper method. If this doesn't makes sense just let me know and I can update my answer with an example @Capan